# How can I register a callback from an Interface returned from my shared library function?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I have a shared library 'myfactory.so' which implements 'IFactory' interface as below

**IFactory.hpp**

```
class INode {
   public:
     virtual void setInfo() = 0;
     virtual void startSearch() = 0;
     virtual void registerSearchResultHandler(std::function<void(int count)>) = 0;
};      

class IFactory {
   public: 
     virtual std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeA() = 0;
     virtual std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeB() = 0;
};
```

Below is my shared library implementation ('myfactory.so')

**Factory.hpp**

```
class Factory : public IFactory {
   public:
     Factory();
     std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeA();
     std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeB();
};
```

**Factory.cpp**

```
Factory::Factory()
{
   //some init operations
}
std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeA()
{
   //creating node A here
   std::shared_ptr<INode> nodeA_ = std::make_shared<NodeA>();
   return nodeA_;
}
std::shared_ptr<INode> createNodeB()
{
   //creating node B here
   std::shared_ptr<INode> nodeB_ = std::make_shared<NodeB>();
   return nodeB_;
}
```

Here is my NodeA and NodeB class implementations (I have given NodeA implementation for now since both are almost similar except few functionality in search operation)

**NodeA.hpp**

```
class NodeA : public INode {
   public:
     void setInfo();
     void startSearch();
     void registerSearchResultHandler(std::function<void(int count)>);
   private:
     std::function<void(int count)> mResultCallback;
     void onResultFound(int count);
}
```

**NodeA.cpp**

```
NodeA::setInfo()
{
    //some settings for nodeA operation
}
NodeA::startSearch()
{
    //an async start search operation
}
void NodeA::registerSearchResultHandler(std::function<void(int count)> onResultFound)
{
    mResultCallback = onResultFound;
}
void NodeA::onResultFound(int count)
{
   //we need to call here the registered function using registerSearchResultHandler
   mResultCallback (count);
}
```

Here is how I used the library interface (I have already written DLLoader implementation to load the .so dynamically which I am not given here as it out of scope)

**main.cpp**

```
void NodeA_SearchResult(int count)
{
    //print count here
}

void main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<DLLoader<IFactory>> loader = std::make_shared<dlloader::DLLoader<IFactory>>("myfactory.so");
    loader->DLOpenLib();
    std::shared_ptr<IFactory> myfactory = loader->DLGetInstance();
    std::shared_ptr<INode> nodeA  = myfactory->createNodeA();

    //here I want to register the function 'NodeA_SearchResult' with nodeA instance
    //I am expecting something like nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler(NodeA_SearchResult)
    //How can I do this ? Does 'dlsym(loader, "registerSearchResultHandler")' can be used here 
    //since my library interface does not directly expose registerSearchResultHandler function' 
}
```

Comment: `I am expecting something like nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler(NodeA_SearchResult)` Exactly, so just write exactly that `nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler(NodeA_SearchResult)`.

Comment: You provided a lot of information of what you want, and mostly what you've done, and buried in a comment, ask what I think is the most pertinent question: *"I am expecting something like `nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler(NodeA_SearchResult)`"* - So.. what happened when you tried that? *That* seems to be missing from your post.

Comment: my bad, simply my thought goes wrong with different direction with dlsym. I should have tried calling 'nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler; directly. Thanks @KamilCuk for directing me back to simply calling nodeA->registerSearchResultHandler(NodeA_SearchResult). Tried with std::bind inside registerSearchResultHandler and it simply works. ! Thanks